# How to erase coverage data before run test case?

Tags: coverage.py

I use coverage API in WSGI project. When I not run test case,the coverage report reach 30%. So, I want to erase coverage data before run test case and also after start up WSGI project.

I set a socket port in `control.py start()`. After run start command  `gunicorn -c guniconf.py --env myapp.wsgi`, I send **6300** port "clean".But I couldn't remove the in-memory data collected.

[image]

Comment: Why try to exclude the data that is measured when you don't run a test case?

Comment: I tried this method，but some of files also need tested.So I only want to erase coverage data before run test case，How to do?

Comment: You haven't explained why you want to erase coverage data at all.  Run your test, look at the lines that are run.  Why erase any data?

Comment: Alright, I got it. Thanks，O(∩_∩)O~~